# Angular2localization and Ionic2 : ctorParameters.map is not a function Error at import

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm running into an issue trying to import angular2localization modules into my Ionic2 application.

if I add these lines into my `imports` array `app.module.ts` file like the documentation specifies [here](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization/blob/master/doc/spec.md#Appendix%20A) :

```
LocaleModule.forRoot(),
LocalizationModule.forRoot()
```

the console will prompt this error : ctorParameters.map is not a function.

Did I do anything wrong?
My Angular version is 2.1.1, so I tried to load the 1.1.1 version of the lib to match the Angular version required, bu I still get the same error.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No... I din't find any solution for the moment.